# Bash date command and extra space when using quotes

Tags: bash, date

Why is it that an extra space is generated when date command is place into quotes.

```
echo Started at $(date)    # "Started at Thu Dec 6 07:26:59 PST 2018"
echo "Started at $(date)"  # "Started at Thu Dec  6 07:26:59 PST 2018"
```

Both commands above should produce the same thing, but they don't.  There is an extra space in front of the 6.  How can I make it the same or is there a way to make it the same?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) is an excellent read to explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us run only `date` command and see what output it gives us.

```
date
Thu Dec  6 10:37:15 EST 2018
```

Since `"` keeps original spaces save in them so when you are running your 2nd command as follows then it keeps that space save.

```
echo "Started at $(date)"
Started at Thu Dec  6 10:36:46 EST 2018
```

*So we should actually say it is NOT adding extra space instead of keeping the original space in output.*

Comment: Exactly: `echo` prints its arguments separated by one space each, and because the first invocation is unquoted, `$(date)` expands to all the words it consists of and the double space gets squeezed due to word splitting.